# Conditional insert using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a fairly simple DB model called `Payout` with an `amount_cents` attribute. I'd like to insert a new `Payout` only when the `amount_cents` is less than the sum of another model called `Payment`, the query for a `Payment` can be expressed as follows

```
        self.session.query(
            func.sum(Payment.amount_cents) > payout.amount_cents
        )
```

is there a way to conditionally fail an entire transaction in SQLAlchemy if that query comes back as false? Currently I'm inserting using the following syntax

```
   self.session.add(payout)
   self.session.commit()
```

Comment: if query_return==False: pass

Comment: @D.L are you suggesting it's handled in the application code where the insert & query run separately? The issue with that is race conditions where multiple inserts are running concurrently (and thus you payout > balance potentially)

Comment: it is hard to say without the rest of the code or a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
, but, generally yes you can do it in the code.

Comment: You can't do it in the application layer, because it produces a race condition.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting?